# Team Foundation Server checkin deleted files with tf.exe command

Tags: tfs

Using Tf.exe by command line, how do I make the checkin of deleted files?

example:

**Step 1:**

My workfolder contains: file1.txt, file2.txt, file3.txt

TFS contains: file1.txt, file2.txt, file3.txt

**The two environments are aligned.**

**Step 2:**

I delete file *file1.txt* from Workfolder and then I checkin all with command **tf checkin /recursive /noprompt** but the file *File1.txt* is not deleted from tfs

Comment: `I delete the file file1.txt from Workfolder`.  What do you mean?  You used TFS to delete it or you manually deleted it from disk?

Comment: files in workfolder are updated by an automatic process out of my control.
Files are deleted from disk.

Comment: You are going to have to get that process under your control then.

Answer (score 0):

If the manual delete outside of Visual Studio and the context of TFS then you are likely using a Server Workspace.

In server workspaces you need to do all operations against TFS. You should not be deleting from the disk directly.

To remove this issue you can switch to Local Workspaces that will auto detect deleted.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb892960.aspx

Comment: My problem is to "promote candidate changes" with tf.exe command line.
With command "tf checkin", deleted files are excluded from checkin and remain in tfs

Comment: They are only excluded in Server Workspace. Switch to local workspaces.